# Using external files and modules in perl PAR Packer

Tags: perl, par, packer

I'm having some trouble using the pp command to create standalone executables on a Linux machine. It seems that every tutorial says a different thing and I'm a bit confused. I'd like your help regarding two issues:
1. I'm trying to include a module created by me (.pm file), but not sure how to do so and keep getting error messages. Should I use the -M option? or should it be -B? And once the module is included, how do I call it from the script? the usual way (i.e. "use module" and then "module::sub")?
2. I want to include some text files too. So far, I've tried -a and -l options, but not sure if they actually work. Which one should I use? Also, how do I open these files? For instance, if I pack the file tmp.txt, what should the open command look like?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Adding modules with the `-M` option and use the module as usual.
2. Adding your text file with the `-a` option, from [pp's manual](http://search.cpan.org/~rschupp/PAR-Packer-1.014/lib/pp.pm#OPTIONS):

> By default, files are placed under / inside the package with their original names.

so you should be able to read these text files with:

```perl
my $content = PAR::read_file('your_file.txt');
```

Comment: Thanks, but adding the file still does not work for me. Can you give a more detailed explanation for what the values of $RealBin should be? Also, do I really have to use this module? Why can't I just refer to "/tmp.txt" as the path to the file?

Comment: `$RealBin` should contain directory of the unpacked file, something like `/tmp/par-xxxxxxxx/cache-xxxxxx/`